# Merge 2 arrays in CakePHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have two arrays array1 and array2. I want to merge these two arrays into one and show the values of merged array in a dropdown. I want the values in a way that the value of first array - value of 2nd array.

e.g:

```
$employeePlaces1 = array(1, 2, 4,9);
$employeePlaces2 = array(3, 5, 6,7);
```

I want in dropdown the value as `$employeePlaces1[0]-$employeePlaces2[1]`,
`$employeePlaces1[0]-$employeePlaces2[1]`.

```
    1-3,
    2-5,
    4-6, 
    9-7.
```

How can I do this ?

Comment: Now python's itertools would be handy ;)

Comment: Maybe you can use array_walk()?

Comment: so do you want `1-3` or the value of `1-3` ie `-2` to be displayed in the dropdown ?

Comment: do both the arrays have the same lengths ?

Comment: the arrays are not of the same length. They will have different lengths. And this is not subtraction sign its just a hyphen.first value of first array hyphen(-)first value of second array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$employee1 = array(1, 2, 4, 9);
$employee2 = array(3, 5, 6, 7);

function doMerge($n, $m) {
    return $n.'-'.$m;
}


$c = array_map("doMerge", $employee1, $employee2);

print_r($c);
```

Or in PHP 5.3 syntax with [lambda style functions](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php):

```
$c = array_map(function($n, $m) {return $n.'-'.$m;}, $employee1, $employee2);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `array_diff` function

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php

**Answer for the edited question**

```
//assuming both the arrays have the same length
echo "<select>";
for($i=0;$i<count($employeePlaces1);$i++)
{
    echo "<option>".$employeePlaces1[i]." - ".$employeePlaces2[i]."</option>";
}
echo "</select>";
```

Comment: why not? maybe if you explain, someone could help

Comment: Adam I have edited my question. Have a look again. I think now it would be clear.

Comment: the arrays doesn't have same length neither they have keys starting from 0. Because the keys are the primary key of the table.

Comment: How would I know that ?  I would assume things as per the code you posted. Please update your code sample

Comment: yes the items are not same and also their array keys are primary keys of the table. I have one employee table and other places table one common table is employee_places table which relate the two tables. I want entry shown from employee_places in dropdown as employee name from employee table - place name from place table.

Comment: Frankly speaking , i wouldn't be able to help you , unless you put up a decent example of the same

Comment: Yup, you need to update your example/ask a new question as this has since long moved on from being the simple cakephp question it was.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you could manually loop through them and match the values together.

```
$list = array();
for($i=0; $i<=count($employeePlaces1); $i++) {
    $list[] = $employeePlaces1[$i].'-'.$employeePlaces2[$i];
}
```

Haven't tested, but should be the gist of what you need.

Comment: I have edited the question a bit. I think now it would be more clear. Pls have a look again?

Comment: Updated answer, it's not really a CakePHP question anymore though :)

Comment: Your code looks fine in the case if we have same lengths for both arrays.But in cakephp the keys of arrys are the primary key of the table. So in the above code if we have same keys in both arrys then its fine otherwise it won't work. I want the other option to work.

Comment: Well that's the example you gave. What do you want to happen in the case there isn't the same amount of array items then?

Comment: yes the items are not same  and also their array keys are primary keys of the table. I have one employee table and other places table one common table is employee_places table which relate the two tables. I want entry shown from employee_places in dropdown as employee name from employee table - place name from place table.

Answer (score 1):

How about using `array_combine`?

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php

Answer (score 0):

Why not just loop over the arrays, i.e. do it longhand. Then you can get on with something else!

Edit in response to comment 1:

CakePHP is expecting:

```
<?php echo $this->Form->input('field', array('options' => array(
    'Value 1'=>'Label 1',
    'Value 2'=>'Label 2',
    'Value 3'=>'Label 3'
 ))); ?>
```

so something like (pseudocode):

```
resultsArray = array();
loop
    resultsArray[i] = inputArray_1[i]-inputArray_2[i];
endloop
```

in PHP (assumes size of array1 <= size of array2):

```
for($i=0;$i<count($inputArray_1);$i++)
{
    $resultsArr[$i] = $inputArray_1[$i]-$inputArray_2[$i];
}
```

Comment: But how can I loop both the arrays at the same time. I can loop only one at a time?